# Sort JSON response by date in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

So far I noticed, It is sorting with the first character of the date

My Code

```
$data = json_decode($json);  
$collection = new Collection($data);
$collection->sortByDesc('CreationDate')
```

My JSON

```
"[{"NumberCase":"CCS - 102957","CreationDate":"03/12/2019 16:59:19","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"No ve algunos canales","StatusCode":"Activo"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 107539","CreationDate":"23/12/2019 16:49:36","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"No ve ningun canal","StatusCode":"Activo"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 110407","CreationDate":"10/01/2020 16:58:42","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"Baja calidad de imágen","StatusCode":"Activo"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 115482","CreationDate":"04/02/2020 18:55:24","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"No ve ningun canal","StatusCode":"Activo"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 118120","CreationDate":"17/02/2020 13:36:58","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"No ve ningun canal","StatusCode":"Activo"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 189126","CreationDate":"18/08/2021 21:03:10","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"No ve ningun canal","StatusCode":"Activo"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 189870","CreationDate":"23/08/2021 16:41:50","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"No ve algunos canales","StatusCode":"Resuelto"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 82862","CreationDate":"09/09/2019 20:47:16","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"No ve ningun canal","StatusCode":"Activo"},{"NumberCase":"CCS - 85805","CreationDate":"19/09/2019 20:35:24","ServiceName":"Televisión por Cable","ClientReport":"Se congela la imagén y salen cuadros en toda la pantalla","StatusCode":"Activo"}]"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ZoliSzabó  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are facing is because of the non-standard datetime format. Try the following, it should work:

```php
$collection->sortByDesc(function($item) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $item->CreationDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the date into a `DateTime` object first, something like this

```
$data = json_decode($json);  
$collection = new Collection($data);
$collection->sortByDesc(fn($item) => new \DateTime($item->CreationDate));
```